# Elegant solution in QT variable datatype

Tags: c++, excel, qt, controller, handler

At first I load an .xls or .xlsx document.

Problem is: there are two different classes to handle them and I am not sure which way to go without doing an if-else before every function call.
Some member functions of my controller I can easily solve by just define it twice for every class (different argument type).

So my question pretty much is if there is a nicer way for calling classes member function without the workaround with a controller which has two methods which get called depending on the data type.
Means I have the xlsx class and the xls class and one handler in which every function is twice for both data types.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the strategy design pattern.

Comment: Do you have an code example, what function calls do you have do access both classes, I guess that would help clarify the issue.

Comment: I think having polymorphic classes is the right choice in your case.

Comment: i guess i am going down the polymorphic/strategy design pattern way then thought there would be a neater way doing this